# pass PayPal requests through nginx with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, paypal, proxy

I'm trying to pass a request to the PayPal NVP Sandbox Api (https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp) through an Nginx server configured as a proxy.

The nginx configuration is

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error_pp.log debug;

  location / {
    #proxy_pass https://google.com:443; # works
    proxy_pass https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443;
  }
}
```

A test-request without the proxy is something like

```
$ curl https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp
```

with the result

```
ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

Using the proxy

```
$ curl localhost/nvp
```

I get no answer and the logs show a bad request:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Feb/2016:08:28:50 -0500] "HEAD /nvp HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "curl/7.29.0" "-"
```

I would have expected the same result as the direct request ( `ACK=Failure...`).

If I use a different URL for `proxy_pass` (like google) everything works fine ( I get a different response, of course).  A search in the PayPal api or the nginx docs ended without a result for me.

Has anybody a clue if this setup is possible or how this can be fixed?

Thanks for any help!

Regards
dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer:  I need to add

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

nginx sends per default 1.0 but paypal requires 1.1.

The minimal configuration for my requests is

```
server {                                                                                  
        listen 80;                                                                        
        server_name localhost;                                                            

        # PayPal:                                                                         
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;                                                            
        proxy_http_version 1.1;                                                           

  location / {                                                                            
          proxy_pass https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443;                               

          proxy_cache_bypass 1;                                                           
          proxy_no_cache 1;                                                               
          proxy_read_timeout 60s;                                                         
  }                                                                                       
}
```